# Fancybox 3 - fire lightbox depending on viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox, viewport

I recently had an issue with triggering Fancybox after xx amount of seconds which was resolved kindly by Janis.

I should have thought of this before, however is there a way of altering the code below so the lightbox doesn't trigger for mobile users?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() {
  $.fancybox.open({
   type: 'iframe',
   src: '/contact-us/voucher-request-nc.aspx?Enquiry_Type=Sales%20Special%20Offers&Make=Vauxhall&Model=ADAM',
   width: "100%",
   opts: {
    iframe: {
     preload: false
    }
   }
  });
 }, 15000);
</script>
```

Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use built-in mobile device detection of fancyBox, like so:

```
if ( !$.fancybox.isMobile ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            type: 'iframe',
            src: '/contact-us/voucher-request-nc.aspx?Enquiry_Type=Sales%20Special%20Offers&Make=Vauxhall&Model=ADAM',
            width: "100%",
            opts: {
                iframe: {
                    preload: false
                }
            }
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: This seems to enable Fancybox on my mobile?

Comment: Really? And what device are you using?

Comment: Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact. Great little phone. This code seems to work though I'd like to ensure it's up-to-date :)

<script type="text/javascript">
function isMobile() {
 return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

if (!isMobile()) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $.fancybox.open({
   type: 'iframe',
   src: '/contact-us/voucher-request-nc.aspx?Enquiry_Type=Sales%20Special%20Offers&Make=Vauxhall&Model=ADAM',
   width: "100%",
   opts: {
    iframe: {
     preload: false
    }
   }
  });
 }, 10000);
}
</script>